# Postgres: Display timestamp in specific UTC format

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a timestamp stored this way in database:

```
2021-08-14 12:19:58+00
```

I need to display it in this format

```
2021-08-14 12:19:58 UTC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `to_char` function with the `TZ` format:

```
SELECT to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ');

         to_char          
══════════════════════════
 2021-09-21 23:06:15 CEST
(1 row)
```